# Search Form with SQL from different table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a search form for a CD collection.. We have 3 tables and all are link via ID number.. but for a start i want to get two tables working first

For the Search.php, I'm struggling with get Desc defined. I have already defined ID from both table but how do I get the ID to link to the Desc ?

Comment: You're a sitting duck for SQL Injection attacks with that code as no validation of the user submitted data takes place and it isn't even escaped!

Comment: No worries, i'm learning php course now ... we haven't start the less on security portion for PHP yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didnt select the `catDesc` in your select query which result in Undefined index error. Rewrite your code as follows

```
$sqlCD = "SELECT nmc_cd.CDID, nmc_cd.CDTitle, nmc_cd.CDYear, nmc_cd.CDPrice, nmc_cd.catID, nmc_category.catDesc
FROM nmc_cd
JOIN nmc_category on (nmc_cd.catID = nmc_category.catID)
WHERE nmc_cd.CDTitle = '$pCDTitle' OR nmc_cd.CDYear = '$pCDYear' OR         
nmc_category.catDesc = '$pCDCategory'";
```

will show the result as desired. If you get any further error let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to join 3 tables together, You almost have it.

You need to add the 2nd join to the description table like you have for the category. Then in your select statement add column from the joined table. Example below, I made assumptions about your database and column names you will need to correct these.

```
SELECT nmc_cd.CDID, nmc_cd.CDTitle, nmc_cd.CDYear, nmc_cd.CDPrice, nmc_cd.catID, nmc_description.description
FROM nmc_cd
JOIN nmc_category on (nmc_cd.catID = nmc_category.catID)
JOIN nmc_description on (nmc_cd.catID = nmc_description.catID)
WHERE nmc_cd.CDTitle = '$pCDTitle' OR nmc_cd.CDYear = '$pCDYear' OR     
nmc_category.catDesc = '$pCDCategory'
```

Comment: Thanks, I purposely have not added in the 3rd table because I was already getting error. So I thought it would be better to do it step-by-step. Just want to make sure 2 tables work first. Here's the error where it's not able to find 'catDesc' -> Notice: Undefined index: catDesc in C:\xampp\htdocs\AssignmentPartA\SearchBy.php on line 21